# Booking form works but does not give feedback

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form where people can book seats for a given event. 
It's actually a WordPress plugin.
When someone sends his booking, email notifications are sent properly and the event booking status is updated accordingly.
The issue is that the booking form does not give any feedback whatsoever. 
Once you hit "book now", the graphic keeps loading and no feedback is ever displayed like for instance "booking sent successfully" or "there are errors in your form", even though the booking is saved correctly with both sides notified by email. 
I guess it's a JavaScript issue,Firebug console is not showing any error...
So here is the code source of the booking form :

```
$('#em-booking-form').submit( function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var em_booking_doing_ajax = false;
$.ajax({
    url: EM.bookingajaxurl,
    data:$('#em-booking-form').serializeArray(),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type:'post',
    beforeSend: function(formData, jqForm, options) {
        if(em_booking_doing_ajax){
            alert(EM.bookingInProgress);
            return false;
        }
        em_booking_doing_ajax = true;
        $('.em-booking-message').remove();
        $('#em-booking').append('<div id="em-loading"></div>');
    },
    success : function(response, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $('#em-loading').remove();
        $('.em-booking-message').remove();
        $('.em-booking-message').remove();
        //show error or success message
        if(response.result){
            $('<div class="em-booking-message-success em-booking-message">'+response.message+'</div>').insertBefore('#em-booking-form');
            $('#em-booking-form').hide();
            $('.em-booking-login').hide();
            $(document).trigger('em_booking_success', [response]);
        }else{
            if( response.errors != null ){
                if( $.isArray(response.errors) && response.errors.length > 0 ){
                    var error_msg;
                    response.errors.each(function(i, el){ 
                        error_msg = error_msg + el;
                    });
                    $('<div class="em-booking-message-error em-booking-message">'+error_msg.errors+'</div>').insertBefore('#em-booking-form');
                }else{
                    $('<div class="em-booking-message-error em-booking-message">'+response.errors+'</div>').insertBefore('#em-booking-form');                           
                }
            }else{
                $('<div class="em-booking-message-error em-booking-message">'+response.message+'</div>').insertBefore('#em-booking-form');
            }
        }
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#em-booking").first().offset().top - 50 }); //sends user back to top of form
        //run extra actions after showing the message here
        if( response.gateway != null ){
            $(document).trigger('em_booking_gateway_add_'+response.gateway, [response]);
        }
        if( !response.result && typeof Recaptcha != 'undefined'){
            Recaptcha.reload();
        }
    },
    complete : function(){
        em_booking_doing_ajax = false;
        $('#em-loading').remove();
    }
});
return false;   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form seems to work better if you set the datatype to `json` instead of `jsonp`.

Typically you would employ jsonp when you need to make a AJAX query to another domain, which you aren't doing in this instance.

Comment: YOU ROCK! I would have given you +100 if I could :)